# How to fix the bug ImageIO <error>

Tags: objective-c, macos, javax.imageio

My app needs to get screenshot from the loaded webview.There is a bug which happens occasionally when the image saves over.The consol log is as follow:

```
    2013-06-04 20:12:33.093 iBookMark[5895:707] thumbnail img save over
ImageIO: <ERROR>  CGImageSourceCreateWithData data parameter is nil
ImageIO: <ERROR>  CGImageSourceCreateWithData data parameter is nil
ImageIO: <ERROR>  CGImageSourceCreateWithData data parameter is nil
ImageIO: <ERROR>  CGImageSourceCreateWithData data parameter is nil
ImageIO: <ERROR>  CGImageSourceCreateWithData data parameter is nil
ImageIO: <ERROR>  CGImageSourceCreateWithData data parameter is nil
ImageIO: <ERROR>  CGImageSourceCreateWithData data parameter is nil
ImageIO: <ERROR>  CGImageSourceCreateWithData data parameter is nil
ImageIO: <ERROR>  CGImageSourceCreateWithData data parameter is nil
ImageIO: <ERROR>  CGImageSourceCreateWithData data parameter is nil
2013-06-04 20:12:48.987 iBookMark[5895:707] [IMKInputSession activate] exception caught.
    IMKInputSession: <IMKInputSession: 0x102124cc0> -- 
    NSPortTimeoutException : connection timeout: did not receive reply
2013-06-04 20:12:53.989 iBookMark[5895:707] [IMKInputSession setValue:forTag:] exception caught.
    NSPortTimeoutException : connection timeout: did not receive reply
```

why does this bug probably happen and how to fix it?Thank you.

update:
this is my screenshot code.

```
    /*the sender is a webView,this function is called in the 
    WebView's delegate method naming webView: didFinishLoadForFrame:.*/

        [sender setMediaStyle:@"screen"];
        [sender lockFocus];

        NSData* data = [webView dataWithPDFInsideRect:[webView bounds]];
        if (data == nil) {
            return;
        }

        [sender unlockFocus];
        [sender setMediaStyle:@"savedMediaStyle"];
        NSImage *img = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:data];
        [img setCacheMode:NSImageCacheNever];

        NSData* imageData = [img TIFFRepresentation];
        NSImage* tmpImg = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

        [img release];
        NSData* pngData = [NSImage compressImage:tmpImg size:NSMakeSize(SmallThumbnailWidth, SmallThumbnailHeight) factor:0.2];
        [tmpImg release];
        NSString* thumbnailPath = [PathManager getThumbnailPath];


        NSString* imageFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%ld.png",thumbnailPath,bookmark.bmId];


        [pngData writeToFile:imageFilePath atomically:NO];
```

Comment: It would be quite difficult for us to debug without seeing any code from yo in particular your screenshot function.

Comment: hey,@kushyar,I have aleady updated.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I think I have already found the answer of this question.I created an `NSImage` object and found that it may become nil while using.It was the cause of `ImageIO Error`.I have already fixed this bug.

Comment: would be nice to see HOW you did it!